# Derivatives of trigo functions

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

Differentiate

$\frac{1+\cos2x}{\sin x} $

I tried till -

$ = \frac{\sin x (-2 \sin(2x)) - 1 - \cos (2x)(\cos x)}{\sin^2(x)} $

I saw the solution to the next step which is

$= \frac{-2\sin x (2\sin x \cos x)- \cos x(2\cos^2x) }{\sin^2(x)} $

I'm not sure how to reach to the above step from the step that I'm stuck at .

Answer (score 1):

you have a little mistake it is $$\frac{-2\sin(2x)\sin(x)-(1+\cos(2x))\cos(x)}{\sin(x)^2}$$
i8t can simplified to $$-2\,{\frac {\cos \left( x \right)  \left(  \left( \cos \left( x
 \right)  \right) ^{2}-2 \right) }{-1+ \left( \cos \left( x \right) 
 \right) ^{2}}}
$$

Comment: As pointed out in this answer, you've made a small mistake. Now, you can use the following identities to get the form you require.
$$\sin(2x)\equiv 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
$$\cos^2(x)\equiv \frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$$

Comment: I have worked it out .. now , I'm stuck at which rule to use - now I'm at - $\frac{-\cos x(2\cos^2x + 4\sin^2x}{\sin^2x}$